# How do I obtain the last mod time for a SHEET in a Google workBOOK?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-sheets-api, google-docs-api

I have a bunch of workbooks that have dozens... up to 100... sheets in them, and we do an import process, loading one sheet after the other, on these workbooks that tends to get throttled when we collate our entire body of data. In other words, we read every sheet in every workbook and partway through the process, we get bogged down by the fact that Google is putting off our calls.

What I'd like to do is look at the last modification time for each sheet before I request it. If it is more recent than the data I've cached for that sheet, I'll download it. Otherwise, I'll skip it and use my cached version.

It's absolutely possible to get the last mod time for the workbook, but if I used that, and only one sheet in the book changed, I'd be stuck downloading all 100 sheets in that book when I may only need one.

I've looked at the idea of having Google notify me any time a cell changes, but there are limits on how many notifications are sent in a day. If I were to activate the notification for all the sheets I'm watching, and turn them off as I mark cached data as being dirty, I would still have the problem that I wouldn't know if I'd suddenly stopped getting notifications because I was being throttled. There are some sneaky workarounds to this, but none of them would notice if I'd been throttled for a while, but wasn't anymore.

So, how do I find the last modification for a sheet - preferably via one of the Python libraries?